# Missing "kernel: Firewall" messages

Tags: linux, centos7, iptables, openvz

Where are my iptables logging Blocked messages? I wonder if this is an OpenVZ issue or something from the scripted install. Note, I'm highly technical, but not a server admin. Could the OpenVZ host be blocking and logging outside of my VSP?

I have two newly installed machines running running text-mode CentOS 7 x64, yum up to date packages, and with iptables/CSF.
Also, I ensured machine #2 has all the packages that are on machine #1, though #2 has some extras.

1. OpenVZ VPS (installed with their image of CentOS 7 x64)
2. VMware VM (installed with official CentOS 7 x64 minimal mode)

I performed my extra installs/configs exactly the same on both machines, and I have these lines in /etc/csf/csf.conf

```
TESTING = "0"
TCP_IN = "22,80,443"
UDP_IN = ""
```

On the VM, I'm getting these /var/log/messages when I nmap scan it:

```
Apr 12 17:25:23 mach kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=ens192 OUT= ...
Apr 12 17:25:55 mach kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=ens192 OUT= ...
```

On the VPS, I'm NOT getting any Firewall /var/log/messages when I nmap scan it... but I think it is properly blocking traffic.

How do I even proceed/diagnose this?

Comment: check /var/log/syslog

Comment: There were no "Firewall" messages in /var/log/*, and they did not appear when running journalctl.